# Problems with pandas tutorial - missing file bikes.csv and special characters in keys

Tags: pandas

I just installed pandas and started to go through the tutorial. The tutorial references a file  bikes.csv however I do not see that file anywhere in the installed files or original package files. I found the file in a git repository. When I produced fixed_df (I am in a linux shell, not in a IPython notebook) the column names have question marks in them, ??, that is some of the french characters are not displaying. Consequently I can't seem to reference these columns by name - doing

```
fixed_df['Br??beuf (donn??es non disponibles)'][0:3]
```

does not work. What other tutorials do people recommend?

Comment: The other thing about this tutorial, is that the column names look different in the plots (no ??, but I do see a copyright symbol), but not the same as in the tutorial - maybe add some notes about the language formatting?

Comment: which tutorial are you talking about?

Comment: have you looked at these: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html

Comment: I see you are lookng at this one: https://github.com/jvns/pandas-cookbook, pls post an issue their if you see a problem (this is a separately maintained tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

The file bikes.csv is part of the tutorial, not part of pandas. The tutorial needs to be obtained from the git repository before working through it. The tutorial is intended to be carried out in the ipython notebook. There are no issues with how the french characters display in the notebook, as opposed to the terminal. I think the pandas page that introduces and links to the tutorial could be a little more clear about this.

Comment: Ok, what do you think it should say to be more clear?

Comment: I would copy more of Julia's tutorial, i.e, the part that gives instructions for using git to get it, and recommends IPython notebooks. Or at least add a sentence like: To work through this tutorial, use 'git' to obtain the tutorial data and notebooks as discussed in <site link>. This is the first tutorial users see after the 10 minute intro. I think it would be easier if it didn't use git, notebooks, and referenced data already installed.